# How to display number of filtered records in a label

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am using an access database with delphi 7 and I have records of registered students.I want  a code that can display the number of males students from the database on a label in a form and also the females students on another label. The fieldname in the access database is gender while the datatypes are male and  female. So if the number of male students is 20 and 30  females, it should display 20 on a label and 30 females on another label.Is there a simple code I can to do this using an adoquery1 with a datasource1 which I have used to save the records on the database?
the field names include
Firstname Othername and Gender

Comment: Yes, there is a way you can do this using an adoquery with a datasource. How you would go about it, however, I can't help you with, because you provided no information about your database schema, no sample data, no example of the output you'd like to obtain, and no attempt to write SQL yourself to do so. (It's a simple query using `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`, but without information on your DB schema, it's difficult to provide an example.) Please [edit] to provide more specific information so that we can try and help you. We can't see your screen from where we sit.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
AdoQuery1.Active:= false;
AdoQuery1.SQL.Text:= ' select gender, count(*) as cnt from atable '
                    +' where something = 10 '
                    +' group by gender '
                    +' order by (gender = "M") ';
AdoQuery1.Active:= true;
DataSrc:= TDataSource.Create(Self);
DataSrc.DataSet:= AdoQuery1;
DataSrc.Enabled:= true;
DataSrc.FindFirst;
if lowercase((DataSrc.FieldByName('gender')) = 'm' then begin
  LabelMale.Caption:= DataSrc.FieldByName('cnt').AsString;
  Success:= DataSrc.FindNext;
end
else LabelMale.Caption:= 'none';
if (Success) and (lowercase((DataSrc.FieldByName('gender')) = 'f') then begin
  LabelFemale.Caption:= DataSrc.FieldByName('cnt').AsString;
end
else LabelFemale.Caption:= 'none';
```